# Trying to get a selected view from onContextItemSelected

Tags: android, listadapter, dataadapter, android-contextmenu

I currently have a main activity that extends `ListActivity`

I am inflating the activity with a `ListAdapter` with entries from a database.
I have the inflated entries operating as a context menu, but i would like to be able to also get the value's from one of the `TextViews` inside the selected ListView when it is clicked on, which i have obtained with an `OnListItemClick listener`.

The problem is, when a long press happens to activate the context menu,  the `OnItemClickListener` does not register, and i am unable to get the value from the `ListView` like I can from a regular short click.  The `onListItemClick` has visibility of the `View` when it is clicked, but the `onContextItemSelected` does not, it only has visibility of the `MenuItem`.

```
public class EntryActivity extends ListActivity
{ 
   String currentItemName;

   @Override
   protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) 
   {
       //The Value i need is this: currentItemName, 
       //and i need it to register when a list item is clicked
       TextView curName =(TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.txtName) ;
       currentItemName = curName.getText().toString(); 
   }

   //I need to use the String obtained from the click in the context menu
   //to call a method, but a long click makes the onContextItemSelected 
   //be called, so onItemClickListener is never called, and i cant get the string
   @Override
   public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item ) 
   {
      switch(item.getItemId())
      {
         case ADD_ONE: 
            methodCalled(currentItemName);
            break;
      }
   }

   //I am inflating the list with a DataAdapter and a ListAdapter
   private void refresh()
   {
      //create an array the size of the cursor(one item per row)
      InventoryItem[] items = new InventoryItem[c.getCount()];

      //create and set the DataAdaptor with the array of inventory items, to the 
      //inventoryList layout
      da = new DataAdapter(this,  R.layout.inventorylist, items);
      setListAdapter(da);      
   }
}
```

Is there any way to make the view I clicked available to the contextMenu listener? Or am I going about this the wrong way?

Answer (score 0):

You can call `ListView.setOnItemLongClickListener(...)` and `AlertDialog.Builder.setItems(CharSequence[] items, DialogInterface.OnClickListener listener)` to show context menu after user long click on listview items.

Comment: Thank you for the reply, but I am a little confused. I see how setting the listview onLonClick listener is helpful, but i don't know what to place in the ellipsis(...) as you have described it.  Do you mean i have to make a listener that launches the context menu? Or is it that i will actually be creating an AlertDialog which will list the menu items, and act as the context menu?

Answer (score 0):

Ok so it turns out this was really, really easy to accomplish.  In my listItemClicklistener i just had to register the ListItem for a contextMenu, and then open the context Menu:

```
    protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) 
{

    Cursor c = db.getAllItems(); 
    c.moveToFirst(); 

    //get and store the row that was clicked
    currentRow = position;    

    //register this item for a context menu 
    registerForContextMenu(l);
    //open the context menu
    openContextMenu(l);


}
```

and had to add this line to my OnCreate method:

```
registerForContextMenu(getListView());
```

Way good, works great!